# Swift - Sequence - Why I'm not required to add typealiases for Element and Iterator?

Tags: swift, sequence

I'm learning Swift and cannot understand why I can just declare

```swift
class MultiSet<T: Hashable> : Swift.Sequence {
    var data = [T]()
    
    func makeIterator() -> Array<T>.Iterator {
        return data.makeIterator()
    }
}
```

and that would work. However, if I copy the `Sequence` declaration and write

```swift
class MultiSet<T: Hashable> : MySequence {
    var data = [T]()
    
    func makeIterator() -> Array<T>.Iterator {
        return data.makeIterator()
    }
}

public protocol MySequence {
    associatedtype Element where Self.Element == Self.Iterator.Element
    associatedtype Iterator : IteratorProtocol
    func makeIterator() -> Self.Iterator
}
```

I'm getting errors that I need to explicitly write protocol stubs:

```swift
    typealias Element = <#type#>
    typealias Iterator = <#type#>
```

How it's automatically inferred?

Thanks!

Comment: Good question. I suspect it's punishment for using `T` instead of `Element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the constraint you add in the `associatedtype` declaration is just a constraint, and doesn't actually resolve the type.

To be able to resolve the `associatedtype` you need some kind of reference in the protocol (or the implementation) to that `associatedtype`.

In your example, your implementation only "resolve" the `Iterator` `associatedtype`:

```swift
public protocol MySequence {
    func makeIterator() -> Self.Iterator
}

class MultiSet<T: Hashable> : Swift.Sequence {
    func makeIterator() -> Array<T>.Iterator {
        return data.makeIterator()
    }
}
```

Because you "replaced" `Iterator` with `Array<T>.Iterator` in the implementation, Swift understands how `Iterator` should be resolved. But At that point `Element` is still not resolved.

> Note: Xcode does ask for both `Element` and `Iterator` type aliases in the implementation, but `Element` is the only one actually missing.
> If you add
>
> ```swift
> typealias Element = T
> ```
>
> In `MultiSet` it fixes the error.

If you want Swift to be able to resolve `Element` you will need the same kind of "reference", either in your implementation of `MultiSet` or directly inside your protocol with an extension.

For example:

```swift
public protocol MySequence {
    associatedtype Element where Self.Element == Self.Iterator.Element
    associatedtype Iterator : IteratorProtocol
    func makeIterator() -> Iterator

    func foobar() -> Element? // added a reference to Element
}

extension MySequence {
    func foobar() -> Iterator.Element? {
        nil
    }
}

struct MultiSet<T>: MySequence {
    var data = [T]()

    func makeIterator() -> Array<T>.Iterator {
        return data.makeIterator()
    }
}
```

This will allow Swift to resolve `Element` to `Iterator.Element`.

> Note: You can define `foobar` inside `MultiSet` without a default implementation in an extension. I used this example because it is how it's done inside `Sequence`.

If you take a look at the `Sequence` implementation ([Source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L352)) you will notice the `_customContainsEquatableElement` function (that references `Element`), with a default implementation (which resolve `Element` to `Iterator.Element`)

```swift
public protocol Sequence {
  func _customContainsEquatableElement(
    _ element: Element
  ) -> Bool?
}

// [...]

extension Sequence {
  public func _customContainsEquatableElement(
    _ element: Iterator.Element
  ) -> Bool? {
    return nil
  }
}
```

This is why when implementing `Sequence` you don't have to explicitly resolve `Element`, it's implicitly resolved to `Iterator.Element`.

Comment: Thanks! That really explains